# Double-click to go fullscreen without having video controls enabled (WordPress/HTML5)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, video

I have been given a task of creating a video thumbnail which, if clicked, would bring the user to a new page (I've done this already). Then, once they're on the new page, a single mp4 video(autoplay+loop)will be presented to them.

The problem starts when I am unable to get the video to do anything else, as the controls have been hidden. I can't interact with it at all. This would be the desired effect, as long as it was possible to double click on it to get it to open on fullscreen and then carry on with what is was doing previously (looping).

I have tried to look all over the web in hopes that someone else has has the same issue, but got nothing. 
There's

player.on('dblclick', function() { player.requestFullscreen(); });

for JavaScript, but as I am on WordPress and only know how to access/use HTML and CSS + plugins, I am unsure as to how to fix this issue.

Someone else said to "Attach a double click(dblclick) event listener to the video, then in the listener call requestFullScreen on the video.", however, I am not sure on how to successfully do carry it out, or even if that is possible.

My code for the video is really simple, but keep in mind that the controls that you would usually see on an mp4 video are not there:

video autoplay loop

source src="https://websitelink.mp4" type="video/mp4"
video

Whenever I try to add anything that resembles JS code, WordPress simply ignore it or gets rid of the video.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Usually Wordpress themes and extensions has custom CSS or JS functionality for such purposes. Check if the one you are using has this property. If not, you can paste **iframe** code of the video by restricting some properties. Check following link for iframe properties:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

Comment: It appears as though every extension contains a video theme, which goes against the requirement that I need to achieve. As for the iframe code, it does not allow me to go completely fullscreen. I will look into this further, as I need to basically emulate a screensaver.